# Spring Boot - Cacheable appears to be going into the method every time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using GraphQL and Spring Boot (along with data-mongodb).

There's a specific query I make to Mongo that I would like to be cached so it isn't actually executed every time.

I came across the `cacheable` feature of Spring and feel I have implemented as per the docs but it doesn't seem to work. I've added a breakpoint in the cacheable method - the first time I make the query I'd expect it to go in, but the second time I wouldn't.

Is my understanding above correct, or is my configuration wrong:

In my Gradle dependencies I have:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-cache")
...
}
```

I've enabled caching like so:

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
class DashboardGraphQLService

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DashboardGraphQLService>(*args)
}
```

And then the function I want cached:

```
@Component
class SGQueryResolver : GraphQLQueryResolver {
   fun sg(options: Options): List<Sg> {

        ....

        val results = mongoTemplate.find(query, Sg::class.java)

        results.forEach {
            heavyMethod("abc")
        }

        return results
    }
}

@Cacheable("test")
    fun heavyMethod(id: String): String {

        println("SOMETHING")

        return "Again"
}
```

So I was expecting that the `println("SOMETHING")` would only appear the first time, however it appears each time - leading me to think something is wrong.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Basically `heavyMethod` is being called by me rather than by Spring. So what I did was create a new component, placed `heavyMethod` into that, then Autowired that new component and used the `heavyMethod`. It worked.

Comment: Yes @userMod2, this is the case, local calls doesnt work with annotations. But you can also direct inject CacheManager and manually get/put from the cache inside the method, so you don't need to create a new component for it.